# Replace &amp; with &

Tags: mysql, drupal-8

When running the following code, I'm encountering an error message saying that the semicolon that I used on this line:

```
$select_stock->addExpression("REPLACE(b.corporateName, '&amp;', '&')");
```

for the ampersand is incorrectly placed

> InvalidArgumentException: ; is not supported in SQL strings. Use only one statement at a time.

Is there another way to solve this?

```
public function c_form_db_2($cName) {
    $select_stock = $this->connection->select('stock', 'a');
    $select_stock->fields('a', ['high', 'low', 'stockname']);
    $select_stock->innerJoin('stockdetails', 'b', 'b.high = a.high');
    $select_stock->condition('a.isCurrentPrice', 'Yes');
    $select_stock->condition('a.isActive', 'Yes');
    $select_stock->condition('b.status', 'Closing');
    $select_stock->addExpression("REPLACE(b.corporateName, '&amp;', '&')");
    $select_stock->escapeLike($cName);
    $select_stock->orderBy('a.tickerId', 'DESC');
    $select_stock->orderBy('a.volId', 'DESC');
    $select_stock_rows = $select_stock->execute()
      ->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    return $select_stock_rows;
}
```

Comment: I suspect this means your code is vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: @ceejayoz There's no variable input in that statement, what does it have to do with SQL injection?

Comment: It seems like Drupal just doesn't notice that the semicolon is inside a quoted string parameter to `REPLACE()`.

Comment: I don't use Drupal, but maybe try escaping it? `'&amp\;'`?

Comment: I think this is drupal testing the statement before submitting to insure it doesn't include a semicolon because it doesn't allow multiple SQL statements to be submitted at the same time. It would probably allow this through if `$amp;` was parameterized (treated like user input) so that the SQL could be submitted separately from the parameter and drupal will be happy. Guessing a bit here though since I'm not a drupal expert.

Comment: @Barmar For clarity: the error seems to indicate the *underlying query builder system* being used is vulnerable to SQL. Chances are user input is used elsewhere with the same query builder.

Comment: @ceejayoz I'd be very surprised if a popular framework like Drupal has such a vulnerability. In fact, this error message seems to be due to it trying to protect against SQL injection, since it rejects a query that contains `;` in it.

Comment: @ceejayoz yes, it's trying to protect from sql injection. It won't allow multiple statements. I would be happy if there is a way to do it. Barmar, I will try your escaping suggestion too.

Comment: @barmar, escaping it as you suggested didn't work.

Comment: It's highly probable that someone failed at SQL escaping and used `htmlspecialchars` instead of the proper SQL escaping method. Drupal supports [placeholder values](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/database-api/static-queries) so this can be avoided if coded properly.

Comment: This is a dirty data problem. You should update your database and clean up the problem. This sort of hacked on code does not fix the problem, it just sweeps it under the rug where, figuratively speaking, everyone who looks at this code can still see the huge body-sized lump.

Comment: 100% agree. Fix the code that inserts unsanitized data into the database. Trying to hack around it in SQL is a waste of time, and it will ultimately not work  properly. See https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php and https://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php

Comment: @Tomalak I am not trying to hack. The corporateName field has values such as "Ali & Sons Company LLC. I would like it to appear as "Ali and Sons Company LLC" in my page.

Comment: That's not what your question title suggests, though.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know Drupal but I assume REPLACE is the standard MySql function and that Drupal supports all of them. In that case, if **by chance you are running MySql 8**, then instead of using REPLACE, use REGEXP_REPLACE and match against the regular expression '&amp.' using the wildcard '.' for the ';' character on the assumption that ';' is the only character that will ever be matched by the wildcard.

Comment: it's a great idea but I don't use MySQL 8 :(